# Inno Setup not showing correct icon in Start Menu

Tags: inno-setup

I can successfully create a desktop shortcut with my custom icon, however, the start menu shortcut uses the system's default icon, and not my custom icon, despite the fact that I am telling it to use the custom icon.

```
#define MyAppIcoName "myIcon.ico"
#define SourcePath "C:\workspace\company\productName\productName\bin\Release\net6.0"

[Setup]
SetupIconFile={#SourcePath}\{#MyAppIcoName}

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}";  Tasks: desktopicon
```

Run log:

```
2022-01-11 13:51:02.688   -- Icon entry --
2022-01-11 13:51:02.688   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\application.lnk
2022-01-11 13:51:02.690   Creating the icon.
2022-01-11 13:51:02.724   Successfully created the icon.
2022-01-11 13:51:02.735   -- Icon entry --
2022-01-11 13:51:02.735   Dest filename: C:\Users\Public\Desktop\application.lnk
2022-01-11 13:51:02.736   Creating the icon.
2022-01-11 13:51:02.740   Successfully created the icon.
```

This works great for the desktop shortcut. It is using my custom icon. But the start menu shortcut is not using my custom icon. This is on Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on another (fresh) machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solution for me was to set the icon, using visual studio, from `project / properties / Application / Win32 Resources` setting the Icon using Browse button.

It seems that start menu program icon are cached by explorer so it might be a while before the icon update but the most important is that the .exe file shows the correct icon the explorer, elsewhere it will not work even you specify IconFilename from InnoSetup.
I had the same setting as your using autoprograms for lowest privilege installation.